# Retrieve the name of a shape

Tags: vba, ms-word

In Excel we have the "Name Box" in the upper-left side, but I could not find a way to retrieve the name of a shape in Word. How do I do that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are two types of shapes in MS Word- `InlineShapes` and `Shapes`. It's quite easy to check name of shape object with some VBA code:

1. select shape
2. press Alt+F11 to open VBA Editor
3. in Immediate window execute this code: `? Selection.ShapeRange.Name`
4. as a result you get name of the shape.

`InlineShape` doesn't have name property therefore you can't check it's name until you promote your `InlineShape` to `Shape` type object.

Comment: Thanks. Ctrl+G opens the Immediate window.

Comment: I was looking for a way to reference the actively selected shape and this is perfect. Thanks @Kazimierz

Answer (score 10):

## Microsoft Word 2010 onwards

From `Microsoft Word 2010` onwards (`2010`, `2013` and `2016`) there is an "Selection Pane" in `Microsoft Word`.
On the selection pane the Microsoft Word `InlineShapes` as well as the `Shapes` are listed and named. Clicking on one of the shape names allows you to change them.

You can find the `Selection Pane` in the menu under

1. "Home"-tab
2. "Editing"-group
3. "Select"-button
4. "Selection Pane..."

[image: Microsoft Word Selection Pane]

---

## Microsoft Word versions before 2010

For older Microsoft Word (`2003`, `2007`) versions use the VBA approach (`?Selection.ShapeRange.Name`) as Kazimierz Jawor posted as an other answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17680650/1306012

1. Select the shape
2. Open the VBA editor by pressing Alt+F11
3. Open the immediate window by pressing Ctrl+G
4. Type `?Selection.ShapeRange.Name` in the immediate window to get the shape name

Comment: agreed... awesome find.

Comment: This is dope. Also a very convenient way to set the name.

Answer (score 0):

The most convenient method is to create a macro button, which is accessible from your tabs (e.g., Home, Insert, etc.). This way, you just click on the shape, click the macro button, and voila - the shape name displays in a message box (pop up window).

Use the following code:

```
MsgBox ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1).name
```

Comment: That code can throw "Value does not fall within the expected range"

Answer (score 0):

Correct answer, I hope)))

```
    For Each ILShp In Doc.InlineShapes
    If ILShp.Type = 5 Then          ' 5 (wdInlineShapeOLEControlObject) - OLE control object. (ComboBox and CheckBox)
        ' if object is ComboBox
        If CStr(ILShp.OLEFormat.ClassType) = "Forms.ComboBox.1" Then
            Cb_Name = ILShp.OLEFormat.Object.Name           ' retuns ComboBox1
        endif
    Next
```

Answer (score 0):

**Word 2007**
Works for pictures and haven't tested the rest

```
Sub S___FindShapetypeOfSelectedShape()
    
    '1======= msgbox if floating shape selected
        On Error GoTo NOT_FLOATING_SHAPE 'go to check for inline shape
            MsgBox "Floating shape, " & ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1).Name '"Picture 1480"; blue dottedlines= "picture 4"
            Exit Sub
    
    NOT_FLOATING_SHAPE:
        'on error goto 0 'use for testing
        On Error GoTo NO_SHAPE_FOUND 'doesnt work???
    
    '2.=========
            MsgBox "Inline Shape type NUMBER = " & ActiveWindow.Selection.InlineShapes(1).Type '
    
    '2a_________check for each type of inline shape
        '!!!(to see if msgbox draft below can be fixed)
        If ActiveWindow.Selection.InlineShapes(1).Type = wdNoSelection Then
            MsgBox "No selection"
            Exit Sub
    
        ElseIf ActiveWindow.Selection.InlineShapes(1).Type = wdInlineShapeChart Then
            MsgBox "wdInlineShapeChart"
            Exit Sub
    
        ElseIf ActiveWindow.Selection.InlineShapes(1).Type = wdInlineShapeDiagram Then
            MsgBox "wdInlineShapeDiagram"
            Exit Sub
        
        ElseIf ActiveWindow.Selection.InlineShapes(1).Type = wdInlineShapeEmbeddedOLEObject Then
            MsgBox "wdInlineShapeEmbeddedOLEObject"
            Exit Sub
    
        ElseIf ActiveWindow.Selection.InlineShapes(1).Type = wdInlineShapeHorizontalLine Then
            MsgBox "wdInlineShapeHorizontalLine"
            Exit Sub
    
        ElseIf ActiveWindow.Selection.InlineShapes(1).Type = wdInlineShapeLinkedOLEObject Then
            MsgBox "wdInlineShapeLinkedOLEObject"
            Exit Sub
    
        ElseIf ActiveWindow.Selection.InlineShapes(1).Type = wdInlineShapeLinkedPicture Then 'EMPTY FRAMES?
            MsgBox "wdInlineShapeLinkedPicture"
            Exit Sub
    
        ElseIf ActiveWindow.Selection.InlineShapes(1).Type = wdInlineShapeLinkedPictureHorizontalLine Then
            MsgBox "wdInlineShapeLinkedPictureHorizontalLine"
            Exit Sub
    
        ElseIf ActiveWindow.Selection.InlineShapes(1).Type = wdInlineShapeLockedCanvas Then
            MsgBox "wdInlineShapeLockedCanvas"
            Exit Sub
    
        ElseIf ActiveWindow.Selection.InlineShapes(1).Type = wdInlineShapeOLEControlObject Then
            MsgBox "wdInlineShapeOLEControlObject"
            Exit Sub
    
        ElseIf ActiveWindow.Selection.InlineShapes(1).Type = wdInlineShapeOWSAnchor Then
            MsgBox "wdInlineShapeOWSAnchor"
            Exit Sub
    
        ElseIf ActiveWindow.Selection.InlineShapes(1).Type = wdInlineShapePicture Then 'DOESNT FIND SOME PICTURES PASTED FROM WEB!
            MsgBox "wdInlineShapePicture"
            Exit Sub
    
        ElseIf ActiveWindow.Selection.InlineShapes(1).Type = wdInlineShapePictureBullet Then
            MsgBox "wdInlineShapePictureBullet"
            Exit Sub
    
        ElseIf ActiveWindow.Selection.InlineShapes(1).Type = wdInlineShapePictureHorizontalLine Then
            MsgBox "wdInlineShapePictureHorizontalLine"
            Exit Sub
    
        ElseIf ActiveWindow.Selection.InlineShapes(1).Type = wdInlineShapeScriptAnchor Then
            MsgBox "wdInlineShapeScriptAnchor"
            Exit Sub
    
        ElseIf ActiveWindow.Selection.InlineShapes(1).Type = wdInlineShapeSmartArt Then
            MsgBox "wdInlineShapeSmartArt"
            Exit Sub
    End If
    
    NO_SHAPE_FOUND:
        MsgBox "No floating or inline shape selected!"
        
    End Sub
```