# VBA From Excel to word Moving shapes

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I'm trying to create a VBA macro  that move shapes in word  . 
For example when  a user  enter a value in Excel userform =43 and clik valide the shapes in word moves 43 step 
I tried this in Excel and I succeed to make the code but to move it in word I didn't  find how i Tried alot of thing but if some can help me with this .
This my code

```
Sub lacro1()
rep_count = 0
width_variable = 10
Do
DoEvents
rep_count = rep_count + 1
width_variable = width_variable + 6
Sheets("Feuil1").Shapes("Connecteur droit 2").Left = 
Sheets("Feuil1").Range("A2").Value
timeout (0.01)
Loop Until rep_count = Sheets("Feuil1").Range("A2").Value

End Sub
Sub timeout(duration_ms As Double)
Start_Time = Timer
Do
DoEvents
Loop Until (Timer - Start_Time) >= duration_ms

End Sub
```

What I want it move  shapes located in word .doc based on value in excel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim oWordApp As Object, oWordDoc As Object
    Dim shp As Object

    '~~> Establish an Word application object
    On Error Resume Next
    Set oWordApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")

    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Set oWordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    End If
    Err.Clear
    On Error GoTo 0

    oWordApp.Visible = True

    Set oWordDoc = oWordApp.Documents.Open("C:\Users\Siddharth\Desktop\Sid.Docx")

    Set shp = oWordDoc.Shapes(1)

    With shp
        .Left = 80
        .Top = 40
    End With
End Sub
```

**Screenshot**
[image]

Comment: Hi you again my saver everyday , I'm gonna try  it

Comment: but  How can attach it to a specific shape because in that doc there are alot of shapes

Comment: You need to know the name of the shape to work with it :) For example `Set shp = oWordDoc.Shapes("NameOfShape")`

Comment: I know i'm asking to much but  how can i find the name of that because it's not like in excel that you can read the name of anytype of shape

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17680301/how-do-i-retrieve-the-name-of-a-shape-in-ms-word

Comment: See Bruno Bieri answer there

Comment: I tried that solution but  it  HOME> edit > Selection> selection shape  it select the shape but doesn't  show me any further info

Comment: It will give you the name of the shape :) you can use that name in `Set shp = oWordDoc.Shapes("NameOfShape")`

Comment: I 'm truly  blind I did use SelectShape but I  did'nt found where  ( the text with the name is displaying in word )  xD my life  is too  hard

Comment: That's why i can't  found it , that angle of Selection  is not showing  my Word,, How can I show it  ?

Comment: You need to click on HOME> editing> Select> Selection Pane

Comment: Wait I will link you an image

Comment: Thank you again Rout you helped I'm gonna try something new Now and I will post it if I got problem thank you again and again ,,,,  The problem was in compatibility so I convert the word to the right form

Comment: I will share  every Idea I got here in stack over maybe  someone is looking for this kind of solution